# JCombobox string item (visible) and integer key (inherent)

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox

I have a database schema =  which will be shown in a JCombobox as a JTable column to select a name. But I want the ID field to insert (as a foreign key) in another table.

Usually, selecting an Item in drop down, bring the selected item to the shown area of the combo box.

What I want to do is, when select any item (string) in the combo box its corresponding integer key (can be kept in  a sorted map) should be shown in the combobox placeholder area, so that when take the value of the JTable.getValueAt(row, column), I get the integer key, not the string item value. 
Please help me how can I do that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since there is no automatic way to do it :(.
I am using a Map to keep my values and key.

```
private TreeMap <Integer, String> categoryMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
private JComboBox comboCategory = new JComboBox();
```

Get all the categories (key, value)  and populate the map and combo

```
private void addComboColumnData() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT id, name FROM categories");            
            comboCategory.removeAllItems();
            comboCategory.addItem(""); // blank value.
            categoryMap.clear();
            while(rs.next()){
                String name = rs.getString("name");
                comboCategory.addItem(name);
                categoryMap.put(rs.getInt("id"), name);
            }           
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The fourth column of my JTable should be combobox,

```
// set the fourth column as combo
            TableColumn categoryColumn = tableData.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
            categoryColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboCategory));
```

When editing the value in the combobox, it show the text, but for updating the value in the database table I have to get the integer key.

```
// show Category name in text in the category field.
                    if(columnNames[i].equalsIgnoreCase("category")){
                        Object obj = rs.getObject(i+1);
                        if(obj != null && (obj instanceof Integer) )
                            row[i] = (String) categoryMap.get((Integer) obj);
                    }
```

For database update,

```
Object value = tableData.getModel().getValueAt(rowIndex, 4);
        int categoryID = 0;

        if(value!= null){
            if (value instanceof String && !((String)value).isEmpty()) {
                categoryID = getKeyForValue((String)value);
            } else if(value instanceof Number) {
                categoryID = (Integer) value;
            }
        }
```

And here is the getKeyForValue,

```
private int getKeyForValue(String value) {
    for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : categoryMap.entrySet()) {
         if (entry.getValue().equals(value)) {
             return entry.getKey();
         }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

You should store an Object in the TableModel that contains both the string value to display and the Integer value for the key. Then you you access table.getValueAt(...) you have access to the object which contain both pieces of information.

Here is an example for a standalone combo box:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class ComboBoxItem extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ComboBoxItem()
    {
        Vector model = new Vector();
        model.addElement( new Item(1, "car" ) );
        model.addElement( new Item(2, "plane" ) );
        model.addElement( new Item(3, "train" ) );
        model.addElement( new Item(4, "boat" ) );
        model.addElement( new Item(5, "boat aadf asfsdf a asd asd" ) );

        JComboBox comboBox;

        //  Easiest approach is to just override toString() method
        //  of the Item class

        comboBox = new JComboBox( model );
        comboBox.addActionListener( this );
        getContentPane().add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH );

        //  Most flexible approach is to create a custom render
        //  to diplay the Item data

        comboBox = new JComboBox( model );
        comboBox.setRenderer( new ItemRenderer() );
        comboBox.addActionListener( this );
        getContentPane().add(comboBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        Item item = (Item)comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println( item.getId() + " : " + item.getDescription() );
    }

    class ItemRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer
    {
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
        {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                isSelected, cellHasFocus);

            if (value != null)
            {
                Item item = (Item)value;
                setText( item.getDescription().toUpperCase() );
            }

            if (index == -1)
            {
                Item item = (Item)value;
                setText( "" + item.getId() );
            }


            return this;
        }
    }

    class Item
    {
        private int id;
        private String description;

        public Item(int id, String description)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDescription()
        {
            return description;
        }

        public String toString()
        {
            return description;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxItem();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
     }

}
```

Comment: sometimes i hate java..for a simple task there are so many codes

Answer (score 2):

I have a great and smart solution:

```
ResultSet resultSet = userBL.loadRoles();
            try {
                Vector<Roles> vector = new Vector<>();
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    vector.addElement(new Roles(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2)));                                                
                }
                rolComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(vector));            
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("SQLException LoadRoles Combo:"+e);
            }
```

I set model for `rolComboBox` with a Vector with custom Object, the `resultSet` object contain all data from Data Base.
After when i want get the id from the `comboBox` get it with the method `getSelectedItem`.

```
System.out.println("Rol Selected: "+ ((Roles)rolComboBox.getSelectedItem()).getId());
```