# JTable with JComboBox for DB Foreign Key in Swing: Getting/Setting value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

This is an example of a `JComboBox` containing custom objects with ID and Descriptions in them. 
[JCombobox string item (visible) and integer key (inherent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822928/jcombobox-string-item-visible-and-integer-key-inherent/4822983#4822983)

I have to (generically) populate various such `JComboBox` objects for rendering values for foreign keys in various `JTable` instances.

I am subclassing `DefaultTableModel` in a `JTable`.  We'll say I follow the above example and implement a `Vector` of `Item` for a foreign key field (IDs may not correspond to list index).  How or where does the `JComboBox` selection index get set?

Comment: EDIT-ADD: I am at the point where it looks like I just have to handle what I am doing in my subclassed `DefaultTableModel`. So I will have to use my `Item` type in the model, or bind it to that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How or where does the JComboBox selection index get set?

You need to implement the `equals(...)` method of the Item class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    Item item = (Item)object;
    return value.equals(item.getValue());
}
```

The above code was taken from [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) which contains a more complete implementation of the Item class.

Then you store the Item Object in the TableModel. When you edit a cell the Item will be selected in the combo box.

Comment: Thank you!  I've got it working.  The only thing that was not working was when I clicked on the cell.  The list dropped down, but the value showed up in the cell (and not the description).  I fixed it by commenting out that business of checking if (index == -1) in getListCellRendererComponent()